# Training Deeplab on MS COCO

Tags: python, tensorflow, semantic-segmentation, deeplab, mscoco

I wish to train deeplab v3+ model on the MS COCO dataset. Has anyone successfully done that before?
What training parameters were used to train the model?

I looked up in the issues in the Github repository but couldn't find any relevant information.

Things that I have tried before -

1. I have created the semantic segmentation labels and trained the model on complete data set. It seemed to under fit the data except the person class. 
   I assigned weights to all the classes. But that didn't work out well.
2. I reduced the data set and trained my model on this reduced dataset but it didn't perform that well.

I am not sure if i am missing something. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I am also searching for the same , were you able to succeed by any chance?

Comment: I changed the model. I am training on PSPNet now.